# How do I get flask-cor to return Access-Control-Allow-Origin on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

My python app does not throw any errors on Google App Engine, but the Allow-Control-Access-Origin header is never sent. How can I ensure that I am sending it with flask-cors?

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import webapp2
import json
import flask
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask.ext.cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@cross_origin()    
def do_search():
  if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
    os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/my-instance-name:storeaddressdb', db='store_locator', user='myuser', passwd='password')
  else:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root')

  cursor = db.cursor()

  query = 'SELECT * FROM stores WHERE 1 LIMIT 5'
  cursor.execute(query)
  resp = jsonify(data=cursor.fetchall())
  return resp

  db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this code actually does work, although I do not see the Allow-Control-Access-Origin header when I use cURL to test the url. The logs in Google App Engine show CORS selectively adding the header unless the client specifically skipped it.  Also, the Javascript client is no longer showing an error, and receives the data. It may not be the prettiest python code, but it is functionally correct for my purposes.